Downloading sdk packages in Android studio
I installed Android studio in Ubuntu 22.04. while setting up, some of the SDK packages were not downloaded. Without the complete Android Studio Setup I cannot start learning to build an app. Since I'm a beginner, it would be really grateful if someone could help me solve my problem.

If you have successfully installed Android Studio, then you should be able to use its built-in Android SDK Manager
